# SOUL not working with "ě" character

Tags: xetex, accents, soul, underline

I have the following code in `soul` to allow underlines for letters with  descenders.

```tex
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{soul}

    \makeatletter
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_new:Npn \white_text:n #1
      {
        \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {#1 * .01}
        \llap{\textcolor{white}{\the\SOUL@syllable}\hspace{\fp_to_decimal:N \l_tmpa_fp em}}
        \llap{\textcolor{white}{\the\SOUL@syllable}\hspace{-\fp_to_decimal:N \l_tmpa_fp em}}
      }
    \NewDocumentCommand{\whiten}{ m }
        {
          \int_step_function:nnnN {1}{1}{#1} \white_text:n
        }
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    
    \NewDocumentCommand{ \varul }{ D<>{5} O{0.2ex} O{0.1ex} +m } {%
    \begingroup
    \setul{#2}{#3}%
    \def\SOUL@uleverysyllable{%
       \setbox0=\hbox{\the\SOUL@syllable}%
       \ifdim\dp0>\z@
          \SOUL@ulunderline{\phantom{\the\SOUL@syllable}}%
          \whiten{#1}%
          \llap{%
            \the\SOUL@syllable
            \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
          }%
       \else
           \SOUL@ulunderline{%
             \the\SOUL@syllable
             \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
           }%
       \fi}%
        \ul{#4}%
    \endgroup
    }
    \makeatother
```

I've tried using it for the pinyin syllable xiě but it just doesn't print the ě, resulting in this:

```
\begin{document}
\varul{xiě}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The code works fine with the character set `áàéèíìóòú}` but not `āǎēěīǐōǒūǔǖǘǚǜ`. This more or less makes sense, and I'd nonrmallyjust assume it's an `ASCII` thing or something. However, it works fine for actual Chinese, like so:

```
\begin{document}
\varul{绿} se pronuncia \varul{lǜ}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is this? And how do I fix it? Thanks!!

Comment: soul is quite a pain. Can't you use lualatex and lua-ul?

Comment: beside this: you didn't provide a complete example, but to use soul you need to setup its font correctly, see e.g.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298025/2388

Comment: You could try using `ulem` instead of `soul` if for some reason LuaLaTeX and `lua-ul` isn't an option. `ulem` is a bit more robust, but doesn't allow automatic hyphenation (instead, you can use `\-` to provide hyphenation points which still works).